# Why does this code runs correctly with loose equality than with strict equality?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-of-loop

I tried to code the snippets with both strict equality and loose equality to count the total number of **truthy** values in the given array.

The code runs correctly with the loose equality

```js
let array = [0, '0', true, 100, false, NaN];

countTruthy(array);

function countTruthy(array){
    let count = 0 ;
    
    for (let element of array){
        if (element == (null || undefined || NaN || false || 0 || '')){ //comparing with loose equality
            continue;
        }
        console.log(element);
        count++
    }
    console.log (`The total truthy in the array is : ${count}`);
}
```

While the code gives incorrect count with strict equality.

```js
let array = [0, '0', true, 100, false, NaN];

countTruthy(array);

function countTruthy(array){
    let count = 0 ;
    
    for (let element of array){
        if (element === (null || undefined || NaN || false || 0 || '')){//Using the strict equality
            continue;
        }
        console.log(element);
        count++
    }
    console.log (`The total truthy in the array is : ${count}`);
}
```

I also tried the

```js
console.log(undefined === undefined);
```

Why am I getting the wrong count with strict equality while correct count with loose equality?

I also know there is efficient way to write the same code. So please give suggestions only for the above issues I am facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a chain of `||`s, the whole expression will evaluate to the first truthy value, if there is one - otherwise, it will evaluate to the final (falsey) value. So

```
(null || undefined || NaN || false || 0 || '')
```

is equivalent to

```
('')
```

With strict equality, none of the array items are the empty string, so all pass the test.

With loose equality, only 0 and false are `==` to the empty string.

```js
console.log(
  0 == '',
  false == ''
);
```

With [Abstract Equality Comparison](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison):

For `0 == ''`: When a number is compared against a string on the right, the string gets converted to a number, and `0 == 0` is true

> 6. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

For `false == ''`: When a boolean is compared against a string on the right, the boolean is converted into a number first:

> 8. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.

Then the string is converted into a number:

> 6. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

and `0 == 0` is true.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to add that your code does not actually count the truthy values correctly - there are 3 truthy values in your array ("0", true, 100). 
The problem comes from equating NaN in both loose and strict equality. NaN is always false when compared to anything, even:

```
NaN === NaN; //false
NaN == NaN; //false
```

That's why your code counts 4 values instead of 3 using loose equality.
A better way to check if a value is truthy is just to have Javascript convert it to a boolean:

```
function countTruthy(array){
let count = 0 ;

for (let element of array){
    if (!element)
        {
        continue;
        }
    count++;
    }
return  count;
```

}